# Angular Material CDK Layout Breakpoints doesn't cover iPad pro simulator in Google Chrome

Tags: angular, typescript, layout, angular-material, responsive

I am using [BreakpointObserver](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview) to implement the responsive material design in my angular project using the following code:

```
tablet$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver
.observe([Breakpoints.Tablet])
.pipe(map(result => result.matches), tap(() => this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()));
```

and then

```
this.tablet$.subscribe(isTablet => {
  this.isTablet = isTablet;
  console.log('IsTablet:' + this.isTablet);
});
```

As I am using Google Chromes screen sizes to test, this is working well for iPad but for iPad pro (1024 x 1366) the observable `$tablet` returns `false`. I checked the API and the iPad pro screen dimensions are not defined in [`Breakpoints`](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/cdk/layout/breakpoints.ts).

What is the best work around in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a custom media query in to the `observe` function of `this.breakpointObserver`. I'm really awful with media queries, but here's an example that I did using essentially your code. You'll have to play with the values a bit to get it how you want it, but this should get you started:

```
this.iPadProObservable = this.breakpointObserver.observe('(max-width: 1024px)')
  .pipe(
    map(result => result.matches),
    tap(() => this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges())
  );
```

This seems to do what I expect when I use the iPad Pro Chrome preset.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew! I had figured it out using an example script from angular material's GitHub repo.

Comment: @UmairM can you include that link here ? Thanks !